# Math Formula For A Loyalty System

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Basically, I help someone manage a stream on twitch.tv.  She uses a program that rewards the viewers with a virtual currency.  For every $30$ minutes they watch they get $1$ point.  Also, they get a $1$ time increase of $8$ points if they follow her on twitch.  Now the question arising here is what is the most fair way to reward donators.  She wants to reward the people who support the stream in any way including donations, and coming up with a fair formula seems like the best option, but coming up with the formula is the problem.

The formula should be able to prevent exploitation.  She would like to have a flat value for donating in general as support, but increase the amount based on the size of the donation.  An example of an exploitation to be prevented would be donating $\$1$ ten times rather than just $\$10$ one time in order to receive more points.

What is the most fair way to handle this situation, and what type of formula am I looking?  Please help

Comment: What have you considered?

Comment: A direct proportion $p = md$ ($p$ points for a $d$ dollar donation) would give exactly the same number of points to the person that made ten \$1 donations as it does to the person who made a single \$10 donation. Do you want this behavior? You can choose the value of $m$ based on how many points you think a \$1 donation is worth.

Comment: In general, any function that increases as fast or faster than a linear function (and doesn't have a constant) will work.

Comment: @Silynn: The question makes it pretty clear that the function does have $f(0)> 0$ [or at least it would if $f$ were continuous].

Comment: @EricStucky, easiest way to solve this is set a minimum donation (usually $1 on Twitch), because in all honesty, with the fees associated, anything less isn't worth bothering with.

Comment: You might also consider an exponential function $p = e^{kd}$, which could award a single large donation more than many small ones. You would need to take care with your choice of $k$, however, to make sure it cannot be exploited by several small donations. You always would need to make sure a single large donation doesn't give a huge number of points (exponential functions can get out of hand if you aren't careful).

Comment: @corunder Are you still interested in this question?